# How to hide unverified signature in `git log`?

Tags: git, gnupg

When using `git` command line, is there any way to hide only the unverified notices of commit signature in `git log --show-signature`?

Having unverified signature along the commit list is rather disturbing.
These are the example.

```
gpg: Signature made Sat 01 May 2021 11:50:30 AM WIB
gpg:                using RSA key 4AEE18F83AFDEB23
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

[unverified signatures trashing the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOraG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could configure Git to don't show signature ([official documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-logshowSignature))

```
git config log.showsignature false
```